# How can i use LuaSec for sending in HTTPS

Tags: https, lua, luasocket, luasec

In my script, i use the library LuaSocket to send a XML-code. This works fine with the following code:

```
local request_body = (XMLHeader..XMLBody);
local response_body = {}

local res, code, response_headers = socket.http.request
 {
  url = "http://blabla.com/v01/Authenticatie.svc";
  method = "POST";
  headers = 
 {
  ["Content-Type"] = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
  ["Content-Length"] = string.len(request_body);
  ["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
  ["Connection"] = "Keep-Alive";
 };
 source = ltn12.source.string(request_body);
 sink = ltn12.sink.table(response_body);
 }
```

But now i'll send the XML with the protocoll HTTPS with a certificate. I know that i can use LuaSec but how? Can someone tell me, how i can modify the code to a working code for HTTPS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add:

```
local https = require("ssl.https")
```

and replace:

```
local res, code, response_headers = socket.http.request
```

with

```
local res, code, response_headers = https.request
 {
  url = "https://blabla.com/v01/Authenticatie.svc";
```

Be sure to have installed LuaSec:

```
luarocks --local install luasec OPENSSL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib64/ #CentOS
# or
luarocks --local install luasec OPENSSL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu # Ubuntu
```